# Width of a scroll bar in android

Tags: android

In my application scroll bar is just too skinny to use. Does anyone know how to change the width of this?

Answer (score 4):

Looking around in the platform resource files, I found this in res/values/themes.xml under the main Theme:

```
    <item name="scrollbarSize">10dip</item>
    <item name="scrollbarThumbHorizontal">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_horizontal</item>
    <item name="scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical</item>
```

So, it looks like if you create your own Theme, as described in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), you can provide your own drawables for the scrollbars.

I do wonder what you mean by they are "too skinny to use".  They aren't meant to be touched/dragged.  They are meant for display, to show you your current position relative to the entire ScrollView.

Comment: "They aren't meant to be touched/dragged. They are meant for display, to show you your current position relative to the entire ScrollView." -- precisely!

Comment: yes for displaying purpose i want it.Please give me the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own theme dedicated to your ScrollView, you can set the `android:scrollbarSize` attribute.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarSize="2dp" />
```