# Android ListView Scrollbar

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I created a list view.I need to increase the width of the vertical scrollbar. I changed android:scrollbarSize. But it is not working .Also want to decrease length of scrollbar thumb.Is it posiible. Please help me.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/list_view"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
 android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
 android:scrollX="0px"
 android:scrollY="0px"
 android:background="#515151"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
 android:divider="#FFF"
 android:fadeScrollbars="false"
 android:scrollbarSize="20dip"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: put the layout in the code... pls check it

Comment: try setting android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: I cant use wrap_content. Because I am using the list view inside a dialog and that list_view should fill the dialog.

Comment: does any got solution for this ?, please post here n help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scrollbar will scale to the width/height of the resource that you specify for `android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal` and `android:scrollbarTrackVertical`.

This seems to be the only way to do it that I can figure out right now, and I'm not going to monkey around with it anymore ;)

So if you want an 8px wide horizontal track, and a 12px high vertical track. Create a PNG that is 8px wide for the horizontal track.  Create a PNG that is 12px high for the horizontal track.  Your nine patches for the `android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal` and `android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal` will automatically scale inside of these images.

```
<item name="android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal">@drawable/png_12px_high</item>
<item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@drawable/png_8px_wide</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

I asked this same question and didn't receive any answer: [android ignores scrollbarsize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622471/android-ignores-scrollbarsize)

Then, there was an issue opened but the closed it stating "working as intended":
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7711&can=1&q=scrollbar%20width&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

So far, I haven't seen a solution, tho I haven't researched that much. If you find any solution, please update this question.